# Quiz Game Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a simple quiz game using Unity3D and Visual Studio 2019 and I've been having trouble with these code errors. I can't quite seem to figure out where I am going wrong. Attached is my code and a picture of the code errors, any help would be much appreciated.

This is the "Using part", I've stated "System"

```
Using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
```

This part is from a tutorial that I was following, it worked on the "windows forms apps, visual studio" but I need to convert it to unity and that is where I am having difficulty

```
namespace Quiz_game
{
    public partial class Quiz
    {
        public GameObject Question;
        public GameObject Option01;
        public GameObject Option02;
        public GameObject Option03;
        public GameObject Option04;
        public int CorrectAnswer;
        private int questionNumber;
        private int score;
        private int percentage;
        private int totalQuestions;

        private void checkAnswerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var senderObject = (Button)sender;
            int buttontag = Convert.ToInt32(senderObject.Tag);

            if (buttontag == CorrectAnswer)
            {
                score++;
            }
            if (questionNumber == totalQuestions)
            {
                //work out the percentage
                percentage = (int)Math.Round((double)(score * 100) / totalQuestions);


                MessageBox.Show(
                  "Quiz Ended" + Environment.NewLine + "You have answered " + score + " question(s) correctly" + Environment.NewLine + "Your total percentage is " + percentage + "%" + Environment.NewLine + "Click OK to play again"
                  );
                score = 0;
                questionNumber = 0;
                askQuestion(questionNumber);
            }
            questionNumber++;
            askQuestion(questionNumber);
        }


        private void askQuestion(int qnum)
        {
            switch (qnum)
            {
                case 1:
                    Question.Text = "What does solution mean?";
                    Option01.Text = "a homogenous mixture that is used for oral, parental, or external purposes";
                    Option02.Text = "blue";
                    Option03.Text = "orange";
                    Option04.Text = "yellow";
                    CorrectAnswer = 1;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Code errors]

Comment: Gameobjects dont have text as a property. So it is correct. If you want to get the text or textmesh pro text on it. You will need to reference that component

Comment: How would I do that if I were to use a button with text from the UI?

Comment: Actual buttons dont exist. The are made of a number of components which you can see. Go have a look how they are made. The components on each of the game objects involved

Comment: Could you use a bit more descriptive title for your question please? What exactly is the issue? Also [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) .. and this question is not specifically about `visual-studio` so please don't tag it.

Answer (score 0):

- [`MessageBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox) is part of `System.Windows.Forms` - I don't see you using that namespace nor do I think it is supported within Unity (might be wrong on the second part though) and/or at least shouldn't be used.

  Rather build your own dialogue pop-up using the Unity UI System.
- [`UnityEngine.UI.Button`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.Button.html) has indeed no `Tag`. You probably rather mean [`tag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-tag.html).

  However, this is a `string` like e.g. `"SomeTag"` and connot simply be converted into an `int` using `Convert.ToInt32` ... so instead you should use the string and do

  ```
  public string CorrectAnswerTag;
  ```

  and

  ```
  if(senderObject.CompareTag(CorrectAnswerTag))
  ```
- And well no, [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) doesn't have any `Text` ... you probably rather would want to make your fields have the correct types

  ```
  public Text Question;
  public Text Option1;
  public Text Option2;
  public Text Option3;
  public Text Option4;
  ```

I suggest you make your way through [Unity Learn - UI Components](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/ui-components)